# Python 2 type code-completion in JetBrains?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, python-sphinx, docstring

```
class A:
  """
  A

  Attributes:
      type (int): type field
      required ([str]): required field
  """

  type = None  # type: str
  required = None  # type: [str]

  def __init__(self, type, required):
    """
    The constructor for A class.

    Parameters:
       type (int): type field
       required ([str]): required field
    """

    self.type = type
    self.required = required
```

Which works for strings:
[image: <code>A().type.</code>]

But not lists:
[image: <code>A().required.</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you want is `# type: list[str]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that's because, in `python`, you declare a `list` like `blah = []` ; you don't need to provide the data type as well.

So change `required ([str]): required field` to `required (list): required field` and it should work.

Comment: Hmm, that works. And yeah, I guess Python lists all support multiple types. Still though, would be useful to restrict that to a single/union type so that `A().required[0].` would resolve relevant methods/attributes.

Comment: @AT Yeah, that would be quite useful. Also, if it works, please could you accept this answer then? :)

Comment: I've upvoted. - Want to wait for the answer to the typed list values problem to be resolved before accepting. - Going to try a few different document syntagma now.

Comment: @AT Wait, which problem's that?? I thought that you just wanted to fix the type of your `self.required` variable...